# Under kitchen sink outlet only allows two devices

Tags: electrical, kitchens

It seems my under kitchen sink outlet only allows two devices at once. I have a wall outlet and I have an adaptor that converts the 2 outlets into 6 outlets.

Then, I plug in the dishwasher and insinkerator into two of the 6 outlets and they both work. Then I plug in the insinkerator and the water purifier they both work. However, when I plug in all three, the water purifier stops working.

Note the dishwasher is 3 prong, insinkerator is 3 prong and water purifier is 2 prong.

What is going on here?

Many thanks

Comment: Just curious what kind of dishwasher you have that is _plug in_? Most of them, here in the US, at least, are hard wired. Please [edit] your post to include the make/model of all three appliances _and_ the 6-outlet adapter. Also, are they all running at the same time when the water purifier stops working?

Comment: Is one half of the outlet   switched and one half constant power? Many under sink outlets are, for the disposal to be on a switch.

Comment: @FreeMan - a lot of dishwasher come with a plug kit.   I think this will soon be the norm as new houses going up are getting a receptacle under the sink for dishwasher and garbage disposal.

Comment: interesting info, @DMoore. Just bought one about 2 years ago and there was no mention of it. Of course, it was a returned special order and I paid about $250 against the original ~$1100 price tag, so a missing item or two like that wasn't gonna be something I worried about. :)

Comment: @FreeMan  Portable dishwashers are a thing, same as built in, but have hoses that attach to kitchen sink faucet.  Usually to save plumbing work if you get one after.

Comment: I am going to guess (and will edit with more info) that half your outlet is switched - meant to use for garbage disposal and the other half is on, all the time - meant to be used for dishwasher. Can you take out your 6 receptacle converter and just plug in two at a time and test this out?

Comment: Can we tag this with a country? This (including comments) makes no sense to a Brit.

Comment: How is the insinkerator turned on and off?

Comment: @FreeMan Mine are hardwired and I was surprised when I found out that many are plug-in. I've researched some (not extensively) and many have instructions for both methods, but not all.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I am glad to get so many responses. My country is US. My insinkerator  turns on through a switch in the wall (this is how the previous owners had it so I never changed it). However, it plugs into the wall socket under the sink. The dishwasher is a plug in and plugs into the same outlet. One thing I noticed it that the electrician actually marked the outlets as "dishwasher" and "insinkerator". Perhaps he was trying to tell me something? I thin what DMoore said is true

Comment: I was able to fix the problem I had. DMoore's solution is the right one. Thank you for figuring it out remotely, when I couldnt do it in the house :) I have another question which I will post separately